# Converting a string to a datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime

I've got a python string like this
"2012/04/08 13:31:00 UTC"
How can I convert it to a datetime object?

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer I read in the manual about striptime thinking it would work but it seemed difficult for me to use. Now I see how to do it. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2012/04/08 13:31:00 UTC", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

returns the datetime object:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 8, 13, 31)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('2012/04/08 13:31:00 UTC')
```

gives

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 8, 13, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: It's worth noting that dateutil is not a standard library, and thus could limit the portability. (Although it is great for the job..)

Comment: @Tim Good point, and worth pointing out - thanks. This just fits and is easy to use)